# How to reference node modules in AngularJs file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, node-modules

I'm using the money.js and accounting.js libraries. I used npm install to get them in package.json and am referencing them in my JS file like:

```
var fx = require("money");
var accounting = require("accounting");
```

however the functions included in the library are not recognized, and angular cannot load - so I think I must be doing this incorrectly.

This is how it's being used:

```
var fx = require("money");
var accounting = require("accounting");

const USD = "USD";
const GBP = "GBP";
const EUR = "EUR";

fx.base = USD;
var response = $http.get("http://api.fixer.io/latest");
response.then(function(response){
    fx.rates = response.data.rates;
}, function(error){
    //handle error
});

...

    $scope.getTotalGBP = () => {
        var price = $scope.getTotalPrice();

        var priceGBP = fx.convert(price).from(USD).to(GBP);
        var formatted = accounting.formatMoney(priceGBP, [symbol = "£"], [precision = 2], [thousand = ","], [decimal = "."], [format = "%s%v"]);

        return formatted;
    };
```

Comment: Just like any script for the UI, you have to tell the browser to load the script before it's used. So, you'll either need to use a script loader, or reference the file using standard `<script src="node_modules/money/bin/money.js"></script>` (or whatever the name of the file is).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan do you mean in the html file? I'm just wondering what I need to put in my JS file so that it recognizes the library functions from libraries installed with package.json.

Comment: Yes, in the HTML. It doesn't matter what you do to recognize the library if the library is not loaded into memory...